# .NET MAUI Android Emulator Geolocation.Default.GetLocationAsync() hangs after being called

Tags: android, geolocation, android-emulator, location, maui

I have added the requisite entries to the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="12345" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

When i run the following:

```
 try
        {
            _isCheckingLocation = true;

            GeolocationRequest request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Medium, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

            _cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            Location location = await Geolocation.Default.GetLocationAsync(request, _cancelTokenSource.Token);

            if (location != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Latitude: {location.Latitude}, Longitude: {location.Longitude}, Altitude: {location.Altitude}");
                return location;
            }
        }
        // Catch one of the following exceptions:
        //   FeatureNotSupportedException
        //   FeatureNotEnabledException
        //   PermissionException
        catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx)
        {
            // Handle not supported on device exception
            err = fnsEx.Message;
        }
        catch (FeatureNotEnabledException fneEx)
        {
            // Handle not enabled on device exception
            err = fneEx.Message;
        }
        catch (PermissionException pEx)
        {
            // Handle permission exception
            err = pEx.Message;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Unable to get location
            err = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            _isCheckingLocation = false;
        }
```

the emulator asks for permission to access the device location and I click allow and then the debug control never returns. No error is thrown, it just does nothing.

Comment: When is that code run? I mean, Is that code running in a Page? Or earlier in app startup? If its in a page, is it called from constructor, or later? If later, what event or method override calls it? Given that you do have a timeout, something is preventing code continuation. UI Dispatcher deadlock, or the switch to show permission dialog (and then return to app) happens "at a bad time". **As a test,** comment out the place that calls it now. Instead, add a button, and call it from the button click. If put a breakpoint on line after code shown, is that breakpoint reached?

Comment: Initially it was on a the constructor of a ContentView. I moved the code to a button click after the load of the view and the same behavior occurs. When the last line runs the system just hangs.

Comment: Ok, that narrows it down. Just to be sure, if you put try..catch around it, and Debug.WriteLine in two places: next line after await, and inside catch. If it doesn’t writeline, then it is definitely hung. Test on an actual device; perhaps emulator never gets a location update. Timeout should handle that, but perhaps is bugged when location is disabled.

Comment: I updated the full code. It never fails out of the try to the catch. I don't have access to actual devices at the moment.

Comment: The code contains an `await`. Compiler will only accept that inside an `async` method or block context. Please add to question the surrounding line(s) that contain `async`. Might be part of method declaration, such as `public async .. MyMethod()` or a Dispatch call, `Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () => { ... });` or perhaps `Task.Run(async () => { ... });`  This will clarify what context the code is running in. Next test would be to change whether on MainThread or background thread. Experiment with wrapping in `Dispatcher.Dispatch` or `Task.Run`; whatever is different than your current code.

Comment: More ideas: 1) Make sure the emulator has a location set, and that location updates are not disabled in Android Settings. 2) Manually DELETE your app from the device, to ensure clean install next time. 3) Factory Reset the emulator, from Tools / Android Device Manager.

Comment: it is in an async method

Comment: My fault it wasn't in an async method. Now it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it is in an async method

That may not be good enough. There **must** be a complete chain of `async/await`, starting at the top - the first method that is called. For example, when reached from constructor, how was it called? If there is **any** step in the chain of calls that lacks `await`, then the code is NOT running `async` - it will **block** the thread it is on. [There should be an intellisense "warning" on the call site that is missing an `await`.]

If it is MainThread, then I suspect permission dialog (or perhaps some other UI initialization) caused deadlock. Thus, the hang.

[Async all the way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#async-all-the-way).

A way to "sidestep" this problem is to start a new `async` context:

```cs
Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () =>
{  // Now on MainThread (UI thread).
   ... await ...;
}
// DON'T put code here, and expect it to see the result of the code above.

//OR

Task.Run(async () =>
{   // Now on a background thread.
    ... await ...;
}
// DON'T put code here, and expect it to see the result of the code above.
```

IMPORTANT: Note the comments `// DON'T put code here, and expect ...`.

This technique is "fire and forget", it *queues* the `async` code, but doesn't run it until after the current method returns.

Comment: Another work around is to subscribe to and trigger an Event in the constructor then you can call asynchronous processes from the event handler.

Comment: @Cef, its easy to start a new task (with async), so why do the extra steps of that approach? Plus now you have an active Subscribe, are you going to Unsubscribe to clean that up? Sorry, it sounds like a complicated way to “run a task”.

Comment: I hear what you are saying, but in my case it makes sense because I am going to be triggering this particular event often.